# AJAX POST request with CakePHP causing 400 response (blackhole)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, ssl

I just added SSL to my Ubuntu 12.04 apache2 server running a Cake 2.3.8 app. I made sure to add https://... in front of every single call and confirmed using grep. There are no blocked scripts that I'm aware of. When I try to make AJAX post requests from a JS file to my server with AJAX I get an error like

```
The request has been black-holed
Error: The requested address '/sorts/available_spaces' was not found on this server.
```

In my JS file which makes the POST request I have

```
$.post("https://www.mywebsite.com/sorts/available_spaces",{'customerID' : self.customerID, 'arrivalDate' : self.arrivalDate},function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        self.roomNumberList.push({spaceNumber: data[i].spaceNumber, roomID: data[i].roomID});
    }
});
```

In my SortsController I even tried to set access control origin to allow everything and disabled security (temporarily), but I still get the black hole request

```
//SortsController

var $components = array('Security');

public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $this->Security->unlockedActions = array('available_spaces', check_reservation');
    $this->Auth->allow('available_spaces','check_reservation');
    $this->Security->csrfCheck = false;
    $this->Security->validatePost = false;
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

Even in the available_spaces method there are no calls to other methods or anything outside of the SortsController. I don't have anything in my Sort model and I don't call security at all in my AppController.

Here's the stack trace. I don't even see a mention of the SortsController or method aside from routing.

```
 CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php line 241 → SecurityComponent->blackHole(SortsController, string)
[internal function] → SecurityComponent->startup(SortsController)
CORE/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php line 132 → call_user_func_array(array, array)
[internal function] → ObjectCollection->trigger(CakeEvent)
CORE/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php line 248 → call_user_func(array, CakeEvent)
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 675 → CakeEventManager->dispatch(CakeEvent)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 184 → Controller->startupProcess()
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 162 → Dispatcher->_invoke(SortsController, CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP/webroot/index.php line 118 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is expected that posts via Ajax will not work with the security component enabled.

According to http://whatswhat.no/development/framework/cakephp-2/465-making-a-jquery-ajax-call-with-security-component-activated-in-cakephp-2 you need to add your action to the Security component's unlocked actions:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Security->unlockedActions = array('ajax_action');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. I haven't gone too deep with the security component, so I was unaware of this. I appreciate your help

Comment: `unlockedActions` works in version >= 2.3 ([link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#disabling-csrf-and-post-data-validation-for-specific-actions))